# How to use Fixie Socks (Heroku add-on) to connect to mongodb via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, proxy

I have a node.js express api which I host on heroku. It connects to mongodb atlas via mongoose as follows

```
mongoose.connect(
`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PWD}@${process.env.MONGO_HOST}/${process.env.MONGO_DEFAULT_DB}?retryWrites=true`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoReconnect: true,
  keepAlive: 300000,
  connectTimeoutMS: 300000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 300000
}
)
.then(result => {
  console.log('Connected and listening to requests!');
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I want to use Atlas MongoDB Cloud's whitelist for the Heroku app, instead of opening access up to all. Heroku doesn't have fixed a IP address but makes them possible via an add-on called [Fixie Socks](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie-socks), which acts as a proxy for outbound traffic.

How can I use this add-on to get the connection to work? [The documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie-socks) gives several examples on how to connect to other services and databases, but there is no help on mongodb. All examples use the FIXIE_SOCKS_HOST which contains the SOCKSV5 proxy URL, user, pass and port, but I'm at a loss on how to use it in conjunction with the mongoose.connect method.

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229390/connecting-to-mongodb-using-mongoose-and-fixie-heroku-add-on), but when a different add-on was used (Fixie vs Fixie Socks), which didn't work.

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I tried Fixie Socks but couldn't get it to work. But managed to successfully connect to Mongodb Atlas database with Quota Guard's static IP addresses following this documentation:

https://support.quotaguard.com/support/solutions/articles/12000066411-how-to-connect-to-mongodb-using-quotaguard

The trick is to use the use mongodb atlas' connection string without +srv command. To do that use an older driver version and it will provide you a connection string with 3 replica servers (each with 27017 port). Then create 3 tunnels at the Quota Guard dashboard.

Make sure you download the gqtunnel package and extract it your app's root folder. Then you just have to add the bin/qgtunnel to your procfile.

Example:
web: bin/qgtunnel your-application your arguments

Answer (score 0):

I manage to connect from Heroku + node.js + Fixie SOCK add-on to MongoDB Atlas.  A few parameters in MongoClient need to be set to direct MongoDB traffic to Fixie proxy.  This is the snippet:

```
const {MongoClient, ServerApiVersion} = require('mongodb'); 

const username = process.env.USERNAME;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
const host = process.env.MONGO_DB_HOST;

const uri = "mongodb+srv://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + host + "/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";


const fixieData = process.env.FIXIE_SOCKS_HOST.split(new RegExp('[/(:\\/@/]+'));

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    proxyUsername: fixieData[0];
    proxyPassword: fixieData[1];
    proxyHost: fixieData[2];
    proxyPort: fixieData[3];
});
```

Some of the MongoDB client connection options can be found here:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/interfaces/ConnectionOptions.html

Comment: This did not work for me sadly. My code is same as yours. I'm getting a timeout error: `Error connecting to mongo: MongoServerSelectionError: Socks5 Authentication failed`

Answer (score 0):

With modern versions of Mongoose, you can include the proxy-related driver options in the `options` object on `mongoose.connect`, and this works both with and without the `+srv` URL modifier.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fixieData = process.env.FIXIE_SOCKS_HOST.split(new RegExp('[/(:\\/@/]+'));

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    {
      proxyUsername: fixieData[0],
      proxyPassword: fixieData[1],
      proxyHost: fixieData[2],
      proxyPort: fixieData[3]
     },
    (error) => {
      if (error){
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log('Connected to database')
      }
    }
)
```